# How to calculate moving average for different starting date?

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I would like to calculate moving averages for each participant in the dataset.

Participant may have more than one visit date, and I would like to calculate the average value in the past 3 days and in the past 2 days before each visit (not including the day of visit).

For example, let id=1, date=6/6/2017.

Average value in the past 2 days should be an average of value on 6/5/2017 and 6/4/2017.

Sample datasets are generated as below. 
I am working on a much larger dataset, with more participants, more visits, and more days of value. I want to find an efficient way to calculate these averages.

```
timeseries <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),                         date=c("6/1/2017","6/2/2017","6/3/2017","6/4/2017","6/5/2017","6/6/2017",
                            "6/1/2017","6/2/2017","6/3/2017","6/4/2017","6/5/2017","6/6/2017",
                            "6/1/2017","6/2/2017","6/3/2017","6/4/2017","6/5/2017","6/6/2017"),
                     value=c(2,3,4,NA,6,7,
                             NA,9,5,NA,3,2,
                             5,7,3,8,3,5))
> timeseries
   id     date value
1   1 6/1/2017     2
2   1 6/2/2017     3
3   1 6/3/2017     4
4   1 6/4/2017    NA
5   1 6/5/2017     6
6   1 6/6/2017     7
7   2 6/1/2017    NA
8   2 6/2/2017     9
9   2 6/3/2017     5
10  2 6/4/2017    NA
...

visit <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3,3),
                date=c("6/6/2017","6/5/2017",
                       "6/6/2017",
                       "6/6/2017","6/5/2017","6/4/2017"))

> visit
  id     date
1  1 6/6/2017
2  1 6/5/2017
3  2 6/6/2017
4  3 6/6/2017
5  3 6/5/2017
6  3 6/4/2017
```

The result table should be something like this, where mean3 is the average value in the past 3 days, and mean2 is the average value in the past 2 days

```
> result
  id     date mean3 mean2
1  1 6/6/2017            
2  1 6/5/2017            
3  2 6/6/2017            
4  3 6/6/2017            
5  3 6/5/2017            
6  3 6/4/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `id` of `visit`, I subset corresponding data from `timeseries` and then calculated `mean` of the `value` within `n_days`.

```
library(lubridate)
n_days = 2
sapply(1:NROW(visit), function(i)
    with(subset(x = timeseries,
                subset = timeseries$id == visit$id[i]),
         mean(x = value[difftime(time1 = mdy(visit$date[i]),
                                 time2 = mdy(date),
                                 units = "days") <= n_days &
                            difftime(time1 = mdy(visit$date[i]),
                                time2 = mdy(date),
                                units = "days") > 0],
              na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] 6.0 4.0 3.0 5.5 5.5 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think this gives the correct answer. If you look at the first value from your result (6.500000), this number should represent the average value in the past 2 day (mean2) of id=1 before 6/6/2017. According to the timeseries  dataset, this mean2 should be 6. (Given that only the value on 6/5/2017 is available)